# Absolute right elements not displayed when swiping in list

Tags: react-native, position, expo, swipe

Edit : Ok so it seems that the problem comes from my custom item list, so I add the code of this item hereunder (my snack is working fine)

Custom item :

```
// components/MyItem.js

import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Image, View, Text, Platform, Animated, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import Moment from 'react-moment'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable'

class MyItem extends React.Component{

    state= {
        deleteItem: false,
    }

    render(){
        const { myItem, displayDetailsForMyItem, itemType } = this.props
        let showType = false
        let type = ""
        if (itemType === "Stuff") {
            showType = true
            type = myItem.type
        }

        let ptfPrefix
        (Platform.OS === 'android') ? ptfPrefix = 'md-' : ptfPrefix = 'ios-'
        const calIconName = ptfPrefix + 'calendar'
        const titleIconName = ptfPrefix + 'create'
        const pplIconName = ptfPrefix + 'contact'
        const trashIconName = ptfPrefix + 'trash'

        const RightActions = (progress, dragX) => {
            const scale = dragX.interpolate({
              inputRange: [-100, 0],
              outputRange: [0.7, 0]
            })

            return (
                <>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.deleteItem(myItem.key, this.props.itemType)}
                    style= {{}}>
                        <View
                            style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5}}>
                            <Animated.Text
                            style={{
                                color: 'white',
                                paddingHorizontal: 25,
                                marginTop: 5,
                                fontWeight: '600',
                                transform: [{ scale }]
                            }}>
                            <Ionicons name={trashIconName} size={40} color='white' />
                            </Animated.Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.deleteItem(myItem.key, 'toto')}>
                        <View
                            style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'orange', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5 }}>
                            <Animated.Text
                            style={{
                                color: 'white',
                                paddingHorizontal: 20,
                                fontWeight: '600',
                                transform: [{ scale }]
                            }}>
                            <Ionicons name='md-create' size={40} color='white' />
                            </Animated.Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </>
            )
        }

        return(
            /*<TouchableOpacity 
                style={styles.main_container}
                //onPress={() => displayDetailsForMyItem(myItem.key)}
            >*/
                <View style={styles.main_container}>
                    <View style={styles.first_line}>
                        <View style={styles.left_part_container}>
                            <Image style={styles.date_bg} source={require('../assets/icons/list_bg.png')} />
                            <View style={styles.date_container}>
                                <Ionicons name={calIconName} style={styles.top_left_elmnts} />
                                <Moment style={styles.top_left_elmnts} element={Text} format="DD/MM/YYYY" date={myItem.date} />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.right_part_container}>
                            <Text style={styles.top_right_elmnts}>{myItem.title}</Text>
                            <Ionicons name={titleIconName} style={styles.top_right_elmnts} />
                        </View>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.main_data}>
                        <Text style={styles.main_text}>
                            {(this.props.itemType === 'Money') ? myItem.amount + " €" : myItem.quantity + " Objets"}
                        </Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.last_row}>
                        <View style={styles.left_part_container}>
                            <Ionicons name={pplIconName} style={styles.btm_left_elmnts} />
                            <Text style={styles.btm_left_elmnts}>{myItem.people}</Text>
                        </View>
                        { showType &&
                        <View style={styles.right_part_container}>
                            <Image style={styles.date_bg} source={require('../assets/icons/list_bg_type.png')} />
                            <View style={styles.date_container}>
                                <Text style={styles.btm_right_elmnts}>{type}</Text>
                                <Ionicons name={calIconName} style={styles.btm_right_elmnts} />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        }
                    </View>
                </View>
            //</TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    main_container: {
        height: 100,
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 2,
        marginBottom: 2,
        backgroundColor: '#465881'
    },
    top_left_elmnts: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        fontSize: 15,
        color: 'white'
    },
    top_right_elmnts: {
        marginRight: 10,
        fontSize: 15,
        color: 'white'
    },
    btm_left_elmnts:{
        marginLeft: 10,
        fontSize: 15,
        color: 'white'
    },
    btm_right_elmnts: {
        marginRight: 10,
        fontSize: 15,
        color: 'white'
    },
    first_line: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '100%',
        flex: 2,
        marginTop: 4
    },
    date_bg: {
        position: 'absolute'
    },
    date_container: {
        position: 'absolute',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    left_part_container: {
        width: '50%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    right_part_container: {
        width: '50%',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    main_data: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 6
    },
    main_text: {
        fontSize: 25,
        margin: 10,
        color: '#FB5B5A'
    },
    last_row: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flex: 2,
        width: '100%',
        marginBottom: 4
    }
})

export default MyItem
```

---

As asked, adding the expo link, [just here](https://snack.expo.io/@kptnfrackass/939c41).

I'm trying to use an example using swipelist found on the net ([here](https://snack.expo.io/BJapc5DrU)).
When I directly test on my phone (with Expo), it's working totally fine, but when I try to reuse the code within my own code, I only saw a part of the elements that should be displayed.

The detailed problem : When I swipe from the left, I see the text : 'Left' so it's OK here.
When I swipe from the right, I should see 2 squares with text in it, but none of the two is displayed (this is dealing with the `_renderHiddenItem = (data, rowMap)` function.

Here is my code :

```
// components/Test.js

import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Platform, ActivityIndicator, Text } from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import StuffData from '../dbaccess/StuffData'
import MoneyData from '../dbaccess/MoneyData'
import Moment from 'react-moment'
import MyItem from './MyItem'
import SwipeValueBasedUi from '../functions/SwipeValueBasedUI'

import { SwipeListView } from 'react-native-swipe-list-view';

class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = { 
            dataList: [],
            isLoading: true
        }
    }

    _initData() {
        const type = this.props.route.params?.type ?? 'Money'
        let myObject

        if (type === 'Money'){
            myObject = new MoneyData()
        } else {
            myObject = new StuffData()
        }

        this.setState({
            mydataObject: myObject
        })

        myObject.getData().then(val => {
            this.setState({
                dataList: val,
                isLoading: false,
            })
        })

        myObject.total().then(val => {
            this.setState({
                total: val
            })
        })
    }

    _updateNavigationParams() {
        const navigation = this.props.navigation
        const type = 'Money'

        let addIconName
        addIconName = ((Platform.OS == 'android') ? 'md-add' : 'ios-add')


        if (Platform.OS === "ios" && type !== 'People'){
            navigation.setOptions({
                        headerRight: () => <TouchableOpacity style={styles.add_touchable_headerrightbutton}
                                        onPress={() => this._addItem()}>
                                        <Ionicons name={addIconName} style={styles.add_image} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                })
            }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this._updateNavigationParams()
        this._initData()
    }

    _addItem = () => {
        const type = 'Money'

        if (type === 'Money'){
            this.props.navigation.navigate('AddMoney')
        } else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('AddStuff')
        }
    }

    //Android dedicated
    _displayFloatingActionButton() {
        const type = 'Money'

        if (Platform.OS === 'android' && type !== 'People'){
            return(
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.add_touchable_floatingactionbutton}
                onPress={() => this._addItem()}>
                <Image style={styles.add_image} source={require('../assets/icons/ic_add.png')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }
    }

    _checkData(){
        this._displayDataList()
    }

    _displayDetailsForMyItem = (idItem, type) => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ItemDetails', { idMyItem: idItem, type: type })
    }

    _deleteItem = (idItem, type) => {
        this.state.mydataObject.delete(idItem)
        this.setState({
            dataList: this.state.moneyList.filter(item => item.key != idItem)
        })

        alert(type + ' deleted')        
    }

    _closeRow = (rowMap, rowKey) => {
        if (rowMap[rowKey]) {
            rowMap[rowKey]._closeRow();
        }
    }

    _deleteRow = (rowMap, rowKey) => {
        closeRow(rowMap, rowKey);
        this._deleteItem()
    }

    _onRowDidOpen = rowKey => {
        console.log('This row opened', rowKey);
    }

    _renderHiddenItem = (data, rowMap) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.rowBack}>
                <Text style={styles.toto}>Left</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.backRightBtn, styles.backRightBtnLeft]}
                    //onPress={() => this._closeRow(rowMap, data.item.index)} 
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.backTextWhite}>Close</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={[styles.backRightBtn, styles.backRightBtnRight]}
                    //onPress={() => this._deleteRow(rowMap, data.item.index)} 
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.backTextWhite}>Delete</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }

    render(){
        const type = 'Money'

        if(this.state.isLoading){
            return(
              <View style={styles.activity}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#FB5B5A"/>
              </View>
            )
        } else {
            return(
                <View style={styles.main_container}>
                    <View style={styles.title_container}>
                        <Image source={require('../assets/icons/cadre.png')} style={styles.cadre} />
                        <Text style={styles.header_text}>
                            {(type === 'Money') ? this.state.total + ' €' : this.state.total}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.main_container}>
                        <SwipeListView
                            data={this.state.dataList}
                            renderItem={({item}) => <MyItem 
                                myItem={item}
                                itemType={type}
                                displayDetailsForMyItem={this._displayDetailsForMyItem}
                                deleteItem={this._deleteItem}/>}
                            renderHiddenItem={this._renderHiddenItem}
                            leftOpenValue={75}
                            rightOpenValue={-150}
                            previewRowKey={'0'}
                            previewOpenValue={-40}
                            previewOpenDelay={3000}
                            onRowDidOpen={this._onRowDidOpen}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
}

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    toto: {
        color: 'white'
    },
    main_container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#003F5C'
    },
    title_container: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 40
    },
    header_text: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 35,
        color: 'white',
    },
    cadre: {
        position: 'absolute',
        marginRight: 10,
    },
    add_touchable_headerrightbutton: {
        marginRight: 8
    },
    add_image: {
        marginRight: 10,
        fontSize: 30,
        color: 'white'
    },
    add_touchable_floatingactionbutton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#e91e63',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    activity: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#003F5C'
    },
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        flex: 1,
    },
    backTextWhite: {
        color: '#FFF',
    },
    rowFront: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#CCC',
        borderBottomColor: 'black',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 50,
    },
    rowBack: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#DDD',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingLeft: 15,
    },
    backRightBtn: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        bottom: 0,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        width: 75,
    },
    backRightBtnLeft: {
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        right: 75,
    },
    backRightBtnRight: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        right: 0,
    },
    trash: {
        height: 25,
        width: 25,
    },
})

export default Test
```

The MyItem object is correctly rendered.

Comment: Could you add a snack.expo with your code? That would be really nice

Comment: Ho ok, did not think to do that, I'll add it soon.

Comment: I don't understand. The code on snack seems to work, and I have two classes with the EXACT same code, but one is showing the two values when swiping from right but not the other. Don't know how to show you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess I found why I have this problem (and if someone can explain the difference I take it).

The hiddenRender function won't display the right button cause they're under `TouchableOpacity`.

And the problem is that I imported `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native-gesture-handler`.

But when I import `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native`, it's working fine.

Try the snack I updated.